# Best way to control checkboxes during update | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

Suppose I have a form to post. It has checkboxes. (Bool type, receives 0 and 1 ). Creates the logic as follows.

```
 "is_has_n": values.is_has_n === true ? 1 : 0,
```

It returns a value of 1 and 0 if true (1) and false (0).
It works without error while I was creating this post. If I want to edit this post I've some problems. So this checkbox was true before, and now it should now be false to me. So I can uncheck the checkbox when I am editing the post. 
I have the following form:

```
{
data.is_has_n === 1 ?
 (
    <Form.Check
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="is_has_n"
        defaultChecked={true}
        isInvalid={touched.is_has_n&& !!errors.is_has_n}
        type="checkbox"
        label="Label 
    />
) :
(
    <Form.Check
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="is_has_n"
        defaultChecked={false}
        isInvalid={touched.is_has_n&& !!errors.is_has_n}
        type="checkbox"
        label="Label
    />
 )
```

That is to me now if I want to set true checkbox to false.
So I want to keep it unchecked during update psot.
I mean. What can I do to check that how I control is checked or unchecked before submiting data?
there should also be taken into checkboxes that there are several erroneous presses.
I also thought of doing a method called isChecked, but I don't think it would be a solution. Because checkboxes may be pressed multiple times before save.

*EDITED | FIXED*
I found solution for this:
I did like that:

```
const [IsDangerous, setIsDangerous] = useState(data.dangerous_status === 1 ? true : false);
```

And my Handle change function

```
if (name === "dangerous_status") {
        console.log(isChecked);
        setFieldValue(name, isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
            console.log("dangerous_status", true);
            setIsDangerous(true);
        } else {
            setIsDangerous(false);
            console.log("dangerous_status", false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be unclear, but I think you should use controlled components, thereby controlling input field values with the state. Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.

```js
<input type="checkbox" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

"value" binds the input to the state field inputValue which is changed by the handleChange. Control the value of inputValue to control wha to show in the input field.